# Understanding how the default values of template parameters are declared

Tags: c++, templates

In the std::basic_string documentation found at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string, the basic_string class is declared as follows.

```
template<
    class CharT,
    class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<CharT>
> class basic_string;
```

However, in both GCC and Visual Studio the default values for the Traits and Allocator template parameters are not specified in the class declaration.

The following is from basic_string.h from GCC 4.9.2.

```
template<
    typename _CharT,
    typename _Traits,
    typename _Alloc
> class basic_string
```

Note the lack of default values for the _Traits and _Alloc template parameters.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These classes are usually declared in a million places<sup>1</sup>. Only one of those declarations will carry the default arguments, because it's an error otherwise.

For `basic_string`, in libstdc++, the default arguments are found in a forward declaration in `bits/stringfwd.h` (which is included by `<string>`, among other things):

```
  template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits = char_traits<_CharT>,
           typename _Alloc = allocator<_CharT> >
    class basic_string;
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Not to be taken literally.</sub>

Comment: The header itself can be found at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a01077_source.html

Answer (score 2):

in visual studio it's defined in `<xstring>` way in the beginning before the specialization:

```
template<class _Elem,
    class _Traits = char_traits<_Elem>,
    class _Ax = allocator<_Elem> >
    class basic_string;
```

The "normal" string types are defined later in the typedef for  `std::string`:

```
typedef basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >
    string;
typedef basic_string<wchar_t, char_traits<wchar_t>, allocator<wchar_t> >
    wstring;
```